# VSCode error 'Java Home is different' when trying to develope on Mac

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develope my java app on Mac usig Gradle + openjdk. I have installed the openjdk using homebrew.

When I open my workspace in VSCode, I get the following error...

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip'.
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/myusername/.gradle/daemon,pid=13909,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=utf8,-Duser.country=CA,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=2e7a0e3f-ef48-46c7-add0-0230d33c95eb,javaHome=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.12/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/myusername/.gradle/daemon,pid=13916,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=utf8,-Duser.country=CA,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

When I run echo $JAVA_HOME I get the following output...

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11
```

Comment: Have you tried running your application from console with gradle lifecycle?

Comment: @Tugrul The app builds and runs fine using gradle from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the setting `java.import.gradle.java.home` in VS Code with your expected javaHome path?